# using a generic method when using interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

Im stuck on a generics issue.
I have a method that returns DbSet from a DbContext object based on the object type.

Now I want to write I method where I pass in a object that implements a interface called IBaseData (that all entities implements). I want to use the existing method to return the correct DbSet based on the type of the IBaseData object, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried various versions of , typeof and gettype.

**Existing method**:

```
public GenericRepository<T> GetRepo<T>() where T : class
{
    return new GenericRepository<T>(_context);
}
```

**New method (*this is just what Im trying to do*)**:

```
public async Task SetDateLastInvoked<T>(IBaseData data, int id)
{
    var tmp = GetRepo<typeof(data)>().Where(obj => obj.Id.Equals(id));
    tmp.DateLastInvoked = DateTime.Now;

    await SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: If you are using EF the problem you will run into is that EF does not support querying on interface properties, at least it didn't last I checked. This applies even if you are in a generic method

Comment: Ah okei. But what if all the entities derive from a class that implements the interface. So I don't pass in the interface but the object that implements it, if you understand what I mean ?

Comment: If you constraint the generic type on base type and not the interface I believe it will work, but I have not tested

Comment: If, the type of `data` is not known at compile time, to invoke the generic method you will need reflection as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method

Comment: What's the origin of the `data` object when it enters `SetDateLastInvoked`? More specifically, is it attached to a context ar that point?

Comment: I asked because if it isn't you can simply attach it to the context, modify it and save it without the initial db round trip. If it *is* you should probably not do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are doing something like:

```
public interface IBaseData 
{
  int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then a method would looe like

```
public GenericRepository<T> GetRepo<T>() 
  where T : class
{
  return new GenericRepository<T>(_context);
}

public async Task SetDateLastInvoked<T>(int id)
  where T : class, IBaseData
{
  var tmp = GetRepo<T>().FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.Id == id));
  tmp.DateLastInvoked = DateTime.Now;

  await SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Usage:

```
public MyClass : IBaseData 
{ 
  public Id { get; set }
}

SetDateLastInvoked<MyClass>(1);
```

Comment: @TheRuler won't hurt to also restrict your GetRepo<T> to `where T: IBaseData` - will prevent passing some type completely unrelated to your entities (which will fail at runtime).

Comment: I think I've done that now.. not exactly what you said, but `where T : class, IBaseData`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this, based on previous answer:

```
public async Task SetLastInvoked<T>(int id) where T : class, IBaseData
{
    var tmp = await GetRepo<T>().Single(obj => obj.Id.Equals(id));
    tmp.DateLastInvoked = DateTime.Now;

    await SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I also created another method based on the same pattern:

```
public async Task DeleteItem<T>(int id, bool removeRow) where T : class, IBaseData
{
    if (removeRow)
    {
        GetRepo<T>().Delete(await GetRepo<T>().Single(obj => obj.Id.Equals(id)));
    }
    else
    {
        var tmp = await GetRepo<T>().Single(obj => obj.Id.Equals(id));
        tmp.Active = false;
    }

    await SaveChangesAsync();
}
```